# How to get a list from txt file and explode it in PHP?

Tags: php, explode

Hi I have a txt file like this:

```
lenovo,pc,mouse
mac,pc,mouse
dell,pc,mouse
```

and I want to make a drop down list of first part of txt file string (pc name). Here is my code but it doesnt work how I want. It doesnt explode it. Any help?

```
echo "Which pc are you using?? <br>";   
$pc = file('pc.txt');
$name = ' ';
$name.="<option>Choose please</option>";
foreach ($pc as $type) { 
    $name .= '<option value="'.$type.'">'.$type.'</option>';
explode(',',$name);}
$select = '<select name="pc">'.$name.'</select>';
echo $select;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'explode' it? What are you expecting as your output and what are you getting instead?

Comment: this code gives me in my option list - lenovo,pc,mouse I need only lenovo. I know what i need to explode it but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Your `$name` variable contains all of the options for the `select` you are trying to build. What are you trying to accomplish by trying to explode that string?

Answer (score 0):

you must explode $type

```
echo "Which pc are you using?? <br>";   
$pc = file('pc.txt');
$name = ' ';
$name.="<option>Choose please</option>";
foreach ($pc as $type) { 
    $pc_name = explode(',',$type);
    $name .= '<option value="'.$pc_name[0].'">'.$pc_name[0].'</option>';
    // explode(',',$name);
}
$select = '<select name="pc">'.$name.'</select>';
echo $select;
```

Answer (score 0):

Break up the lines from the file inside of the loop where you are creating the options.

```
echo "Which pc are you using?? <br>";   
$pc = file('pc.txt');
$name = ' ';
$name.="<option>Choose please</option>";
foreach ($pc as $type) { 
    $type = explode(',',$name);
    $name .= '<option value="'.$type[0] . '">' . $type[0] . '</option>';
}
$select = '<select name="pc">'.$name.'</select>';
echo $select;
```